# Create common interfaces for multiple similar databases in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net, ado

I am currently running into the issue of having to work with multiple databases that are very similar to each other, but have some differences in their structure. For legacy reasons, updating the database to all have the same structure is not possible. 
My current project strucute is as following:

```
public DBContextA : DBContext
{
    DBSet<TypeA> TypeA { get; }

    // Other DBSets
}

public DBContextB : DBContext
{
    DBSet<TypeB> TypeB { get; }

    // Other DBSets
}

public interface ICommon
{
    long ID { get; set; }
}

public class TypeA : ICommon
{
    long ID { get; set; }

    // Other Properties
}

public class TypeB : ICommon
{
    long ID { get; set; }

    // Other Properties
}
```

I now want to query all ICommons from a DBContext. My current code looks like this:

```
// GetContextByConnection gets the context via reflection based on the selected database
using (var context = GetContextByConnection(connection))
{
    return context.Set<ICommon>().ToList();
}
```

The selection of the correct database works with the ConnectionString overload of the DBContext, but I get the exception

```
"the entity type ICommon is not part of the model for the current context"
```

which makes sense. But the question is how can I query ICommons?

Comment: And how EF will understand to which table you are performing query if you are not specifying table name (via `DbSet<SomeEntity>`)?! What task you are doing? What is the aim of doing queries using interface?

Comment: Later on I will use the queries values to display informtion in an UI. In the example code above I want to later display the ID for example.

Comment: You don't want to write similar queries, and want to write it only one time by wrapping it into some method? If yes, then your method should be **generic** method, with `where T: ICommon`. You must understand, that by doing this you will be able to operate ONLY with properties defined in your interface in this generic method.